# How to execute a scheduled task with "schtasks" without opening a new command line window?

Tags: windows-xp, batch, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that creates a scheduled task using `schtasks` like this:

```
schtasks /create /tn my_task_name 
                 /tr "...\my_path\my_task.bat"
                 /sc daily
                 /st 10:00:00 
                 /s \\my_computer_name 
                 /u my_username    
                 /p my_password
```

It works OK except the fact that when `my_task.bat` is executed - a new command line window is opened (and closed after execution).

I would like to avoid opening this new window (i.e. to run the task in quiet mode, in the background).

I thought to use

```
start /b ...\my_path\my_task.bat
```

but I don't know how, because since I have to call `start` from the batch file I need to precede it with `cmd /c`, which again causes the new window to open.

How could I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used this code to solve the problem:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "...\my_task.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

saved it in `run_my_task.vbs` and scheduled `run_my_task.vbs` with `schtasks` as above.

Comment: Whatever works.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're seeing the box because the account you set to run it as is your own. Try either of these:

1: Run the task as the user NT Authority\System

2: Make a new account and set the task to run with its credentials

Comment: Could you add more details regarding the first option ? I don't really understand what `Authority\System` is. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Misha: NT Authority\System is sort of an unadvertised system account that is responsible for running basic Windows services. Stuff that goes on all the time in many cases requires credentials and this is the way Windows handles it. Hit ctrl+alt+del, open task manager and tab to processes. You'll see many that are listed as user "System." That is NT Authority\System. When you go to set up the task using NT Authority\System, you'll not have to enter a password. Just leave that blank.

Comment: I tried to set `/u "NT Authority\System" /p ""`, and got the following error: `ERROR: Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again..`. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That sounds like you might have something in your batch file open under your own credentials already--perhaps a network drive. I would need to see your batch file (mytask.bat) to answer knowledgeably.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by specifying /RU option for schtasks. This option

> specifies the user account (user
>   context) under which the task runs.
>   For the system account, valid values
>   are "", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" or
>   "SYSTEM".

And thus, try this

```
schtasks /create /tn my_task_name 
                  ....
                 /st 10:00:00 
                 /ru "SYSTEM"
                 ....
```

Comment: So for some values of `/RU` the command-line window suppressed? Which ones? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Nope. I even didn't try to find. I found this workaround to solve my problem in some blog post and utilized it.

Comment: schtasks /create /? you get the help message and ref this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks#BKMK_sys_perms

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the `AT` command and don't include the `/interactive` switch.

Example:
`AT \\my_computer_name 10:00AM /EVERY:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su "...\my_path\my_task.bat"`

If you need specific credentials for my_task.bat to run under, you will pobably have to put `RUNAS` in the command because I *believe* the command will run under the security context of the Schedule (Task Scheduler) service which is the "Local System" account.  Adding the `RUNAS` command and switches before you BAT file should fix that.