# How do I make a scheduled action in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I need to run `MyProg.exe` every 5 minutes. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into Start>All Programs>Accessories>System Tools>Scheduled Tasks. Use the "Add a Scheduled Task" wizard, and browse to your program if it is not listed. Choose "one time only" when prompted for how often you want to to do it (you will change this in a moment). At the end of the wizard, click "Open advanced properties for this task when I click Finish".

Once you complete this, you will be able to go to the Schedule tab>Advanced and set the job to go off every 5 minutes.

[image]

I could not find a way to make this go longer than 9999 hours, but you can do it from a command line using Schtasks:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true