# How can I modify the BAT file in this post so it will randomly select 1 background contained in a folder containing multiple backgrounds?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, script, batch-file

Is there a way to modify the bat file from this post here: [How do I set the desktop background on Windows from a script?](https://superuser.com/questions/277805/how-do-i-set-the-desktop-background-on-windows-from-a-script)
so that it will randomly select 1 background image from a folder containing multiple images??? AND I would also like the background to randomly change to one of the backgrounds randomly contained in the same folder. If this is possible how would I modify the bat file below???

```
@echo off
reg add "hkcu\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f 
reg add "hkcu\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\[LOCATION OF WALLPAPER HERE]" /f 
reg delete "hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperStyle /f
reg add "hkcu\control panel\desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /t REG_SZ /d 2 /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 
exit
```

Also I noticed that this bat file won't work usually (9 times out of 10)... I receive an **"ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."**

I have Windows 7 64-BIT Home Premium Service Pack 1